# Apache pdfbox not recognizing few links as annotations

Tags: java, annotations, pdfbox

I am using Apache PDFBox to parse PDF files and replace link URLs in it. I am using `page.getAnnotations()` to get the links on the PDF page (please see the code below).

The code works for some links, but not for others. The reason seems to be that `Apache PDFBox` is not recognizing some of the links. Any ideas why this may happen?

```java
if (doc != null && doc.getDocumentCatalog() != null) {
  List allPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
  for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
    PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
    List annotations = page.getAnnotations();
    for (int j = 0; j < annotations.size(); j++) {
      PDAnnotation annot = (PDAnnotation) annotations.get(j);
      if (annot instanceof PDAnnotationLink) {
        PDAnnotationLink link = (PDAnnotationLink) annot;
        PDAction action = link.getAction();
        if (action instanceof PDActionURI) {
          PDActionURI uri = (PDActionURI) action;
          String actualUrl = uri.getURI();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure those links PDFBox does not recognize are actual link annotations? Some PDF viewers (like Adobe Acrobat) by default recognize URLs in the static page content and display them like they were link annotations. Please share an example PDF with not-recognized link annotations for analysis.

Comment: Can you please help me understand what are  actual link annotations criteria in PDF.

Comment: Actual link annotations are entries in the annotations table which define a "hot area" and connect this with an URI.

Comment: Is it possible to replace a link text along with link url using pdfbox? Can you please share some sample to achieve this.

Comment: Considering your code where you expect a to find a `PDActionURI` link action: A **Link** annotation does not necessarily have a `PDActionURI` action. It may not have an **A**ction at all but instead a **Dest**ination. And even if it has an **A**ction, it might be a different one, even a chain of actions.

Comment: Editing the static page content (or any PDF content stream) is non-trivial in general.

Comment: @user14392215 PDF isn't made for editing. Replacing the visible text is extremely tricky, see https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html#why-was-the-replacetext-example-removed%3F